# C++11 lambda operator namespace conflict

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have three files, main.cpp, a.cpp and b.cpp. The main() function just calls a function in a.cpp, and then in b.cpp -- and I get a SIGSEGV. As far as I can tell, it looks like the lambda functions used with my sort() are conflicting with each other. Compile command line order is important; if I compile the files via:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp
```

The code crashes (I get "`*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated`"), but if I switch "a.cpp" and "b.cpp":

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp b.cpp a.cpp
```

it runs fine (I'm not saying anything about whether it "works" or not, just SIGSEGV vs no-SIGSEGV).

Here's the smallest code samples I could generate for the three files:

main.cpp:

```
extern void spud1 (void);
extern void spud2 (void);

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    spud1 ();
    spud2 ();
}
```

a.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Database
{
    int     pubdate;
    string  title;
    string  link;
};

static vector <Database> database;

void
spud1 (void)
{
    int     i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        database.push_back ({});
    }

    sort(database.begin(), database.end(),
        [] (const Database& a, const Database& b)
        {
            return (a.pubdate > b.pubdate);
        });
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Database
{
    unsigned        serial;
    double          calories;
    double          carbs;
    double          sodium;
    double          sugar;
};

static vector <Database> database;

void
spud2 (void)
{
    int     i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        database.push_back ({});
    }

    sort(database.begin(), database.end(),
        [] (const Database& a, const Database& b)
        {
            return (a.serial > b.serial);
        });
}
```

There are two things that bother me about this:

1. there's no indication from the toolchain that "something bad" is happening; there are no compiler or linker warnings, and
2. I have no way to make "`struct Database`" local to the module -- if I stick "static" in front of it I get an error: "a.cpp:13:1: error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions**`"

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong, and how can I get around it? (i.e., why is there no warning, is this "supposed" to happen? and how do I make my "Database" struct actually be local to the module? -- my workaround is to use different names, but I'm not happy with that.)

Comment: Put the `struct Database` inside an unnamed namespace if these should be private for the `.cpp` translation units.

Comment: Correct. The code, as shown, is the minimum reproducible test case. Compilation order is important. Using unnamed namespaces as suggested by πάντα ῥεῖ works, but I think that's a kludge -- the lambda operator shouldn't leak my internal (and more importantly, NON-EXPORTABLE) objects, right?

Comment: In the duplicate, especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6380073/440558) is the most relevant, as it explains *why* this is happening (breaking ODR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the struct declarations/definitions private for the translation unit by putting them into an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace { // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    struct Database
    {
        unsigned        serial;
        double          calories;
        double          carbs;
        double          sodium;
        double          sugar;
    };
}
```

Otherwise the linker will use what's found first, no matter if your lambda functions are module local as well.

---

<sub>That was learned from that same subtle bug, we spent on debugging 3 or 4 days in our production code. Not funny, no.</sub>

Comment: Yikes! Luckily, I was able to narrow it down to "a change made within the last 24 hours" :-)